# Is it possible to change the size of a bitmap data instance after it has been created?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I see that there are methods to merge, draw, and copy pixels on [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d65.html) but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to change the size of the bitmap instance.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var initialWidth:int = 100;
var initialHeight:int = 100;
bitmapData = new BitmapData(initialWidth,initialHeight,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmapData.width, newBitmapData.height);
bitmapData.merge(newBitmapData, rectangle, new Point(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
bitmapData.drawWithQuality(newBitmapData, null, null, null, null, false, quality);
bitmapData.drawWithQuality(LoaderInfo(event.currentTarget).loader, null, null, null, null, false, quality);
bitmapData.copyPixels(newBitmapData, newBitmapData.rect, new Point());
bitmapData.merge(newBitmapData, null, new Point(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

or is it possible to clip the size down?

Comment: without re-creating the `BtimpaData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't.

For the sake of completeness, a quotation from [ActionScript 3.0 Bible](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CeMMho6OodcC&pg=PT712&lpg=PT712&dq=actionscript%20Is%20it%20possible%20to%20change%20the%20size%20of%20a%20bitmapdata%20instance%20after%20it%20has%20been%20created&source=bl&ots=KkU0GufOVZ&sig=AFiTIIzpJ-UnV9-_gtXMhC-_mGg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip-ObGxc3QAhWSJSwKHWjtA2EQ6AEIQDAG#v=onepage&q=You%20have%20to%20pick%20a%20size%20at%20the%20outset&f=false) by Roger Braunstein:

> The size of a bitmap is fixed at construction time. You have to pick it at the outset, and you can't change the size later on.

I suggest clipping visible area with a display object mask, if you would like to avoid copying bitmap data.

Comment: OK. I can't doing anything with the masks. I'll have to come up with another solution. Thanks

Comment: May be copying the image for clipping is not all that bad, unless you do that multiple times every frame or the image is huge...

Answer (score 0):

virtually yes but in fact No!
the bitmap data could be recreated, its width and height is static
but if you want only clip it  or size it in smaller area, its possible with lefting unused pixels transparent.

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x0);
bmd.draw(s_omethin_g);
bmd = clipDown(bmd, new Point(50,50));


function clipDown(_bmd:BitmapData, _size:Point):BitmapData {
    var defaultBmdbound:bitmapData = new BitmapData(_bmd.width, _bmd.height, true, 0x0);
    var smatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    smatrix.scale(_size.x/_bmd.width, _size.y/_bmd.height);
    var resizedBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_size.x, _size.y);
    resizedBmd.draw(_bmd, smatrix);
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,resizedBmd.width,resizedBmd.height);
    defaultBmdbound.copyPixels(resizedBmd, rect, new Point());
    return defaultBmdbound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't recreate the BitmapData. I don't have the size ahead of time. So I was loading the byte array data into a loader that would get the size but since the bitmap data instance cannot be resized I will have to come up with another solution.